# what does \r mean in prosrc in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Query to get source code of a specific function.

```
SELECT prosrc FROM   pg_proc WHERE  oid = 'public.sumall(int, int)'::regprocedure;
```

returning the following result:

```
 \rBEGIN\r    ret_sum := 0;\r    FOR i IN _num1 .. _num2 LOOP\r      ret_sum := ret_sum + i*i;\r    END LOOP;\rEND\r
```

From doc:

> prosrc text This tells the function handler how to invoke the
> function. It might be the actual source code of the function for
> interpreted languages, a link symbol, a file name, or just about
> anything else, depending on the implementation language/call
> convention

What does `\r` mean? I can guess it means line breaker, but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the function definition contains line breaks.

I guess the representation of line breaks depends on the client you are using; with `psql` it looks like

```
SELECT prosrc FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'getall';
           prosrc           
════════════════════════════
 DECLARE                   ↵
    i integer := 1;        ↵
 BEGIN                     ↵
    FOR i IN 1..$1 LOOP    ↵
       RETURN NEXT i;      ↵
       PERFORM pg_sleep(1);↵
       i := i + 1;         ↵
    END LOOP;              ↵
 END;
(1 row)
```

Comment: I am using windows.

Comment: Well, then perhaps these are carriage return characters. As to "why": how did you create the function?

Comment: I created function on text editor then, \e to prompt the notepad editor then copy paste it..

Comment: Then you have carriage return characters in there. Windows prefers to end text lines with carriage return + line feed. No need to worry, they are considered white space.